# my jquery ajax isn't working on my wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
<div class="home-thumbs bottom-thumbs">
<?php $home_query_bottom = new WP_Query("cat=&showposts=20&offset=5"); $b = 0; ?>
<ul class="thumbs">
    <?php while ($home_query_bottom->have_posts()) : $home_query_bottom->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; $b++; ?>

        <li class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> thumb"><?php get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'thumbnail' ), 'default_size' => 'thumbnail', 'width' => '160', 'height' => '160' ) ); ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); $b = 0; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


$('.go-right').click(function(){

$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "process_thumbs.php",
            data:   "showposts=25",
            success: function(html){
                $("#output").html(html);
            }

});  
});
</script>

// process_thumbs.php
  <body>

    <?php $numposts = $_POST['showposts']; ?>
    <div><?php echo "this is the amount of posts to be shown: $numposts"; ?></div>
    </body>
```

Seems like a simple ajax call. .go-right does exist it's just in anoher file and I've tested that the click is executing. This ajax call is basically not working. Maybe someone could identify if my code is wrong.

Ideally I want to take that wp-Query loop and use ajax to run that loop again with different showposts and offset if someone clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `.go-right` is **before** the jQuery code OR (better) wrap your jquery in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
})
```

or similar, to make sure that the handler is really attached to your `.go-right` element

Do not output `<body>` tags in your `process_thumbs.php`, maybe this is confusing jQuery.

Check Firebug console/net tabs, to make sure that the request is really being sent.

Add an `error` callback to your `.ajax`, to make sure that your ajax call really gets executed.

---

Yeah, use absolute urls but with a wordpress helper function:

```
...
url: '<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/myplugin/mycallback';?>'
...
```

This way, all of your URLs will be relative to Wordpress root url.

Comment: thanks. I checked chrome's developer tools and it says my process_thumbs.php 404 error. said www.url.com/process_thumbs.php, which isn't the url. I guess in wordpress you need absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite with your code inside the document ready handler:

> $(function(){
>   Your code
>    });

It's working well.

So or it's a position related problem of your code, OR you mispell something.

Follows my test code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

    $('.go-right').click(function(){

        $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process_thumbs.html",
                    data:   "showposts=25",
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#output").html(html);
                    }

        });  
    });

        });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body >


    <div id="output"></div>

    <a class="go-right">RIGHT</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

In Wordpress (I'm using version 3.0 and upwards), due to conflicts with other javascript libraries (i.e. prototype) you have to write:

```
$JQuery('.go-right').click(function(){
```

instead of

```
$('.go-right').click(function(){
```

Also, check with Firebug to make sure the link to your Jquery library is correct.

One more thing...Wordpress already includes jQuery, you can get it by writing:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

The first line MUST go before the second line (wp_head()) or else it won't work.